# How did I manage to assign a server name in Files?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm having a moment here. I have a server that I SSH to. Now at some point, I some how gave it a name to use instead of its IP. However I achieved this, it was not via changing anything in the hostname file on the server (it is still raspberrypi) or the hosts file on my laptop (no entry for the server's IP).

I am able to SSH to the server by its name through the Files app and the Terminal. And in the Files app down the left hand side, if I hover over the server entry, it gives the path to its Home folder with its name and not its IP.

I cannot fathom how I did this but really want to know.

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: Did you by any chance add the ip-address and name to /etc/hosts ?

Comment: Perhaps you bookmarked the server, then renamed the bookmark?

Comment: Definitely nothing added to /etc/hosts. And while I can rename a bookmark - that doesn't account for how I can access it using SSH via the Terminal as I have just attempted that scenario with a new server and while the bookmark name is changed it is only changed there and is not applied anywhere else.

Comment: Should be in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: I can find /etc/ssh/ssh_config if that's the same? But there is nothing in there for any server in particular.

Comment: Ah-ha @pLumo, it is indeed in ~/.ssh/config - which is, I've discovered the user level ssh config, where as /etc/ssh/ssh_config is the global config. I totally forgot putting it there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have set an alias Host name at `~/.ssh/config`, it looks something like this:

```
Host some-name
    HostName ip-address
    some-setting some-value
```